How to override StyleCop rules severity from stylecop.json in .editorconfig
I'm using StyleCop.Analyzers in my project and have a stylecop.json file with some specific rules configured.
Here's a sample from my stylecop.json
{
  "settings": {
    "layoutRules": {
      "newlineAtEndOfFile": "allow"
    }
  }
}


And here is what I have in my .editorconfig
# .editorconfig example
[*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1518.severity = error

However, it still shows as a warning. How can I ensure .editorconfig overrides the severity set in stylecop.json?

If your goal is simply to change the severity of SA1518 from warning to error, I suggest adding the following code in the .csproj file:
<PropertyGroup>
  <WarningsAsErrors>SA1518</WarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>

I tested this and it worked. Hope this helps!
